# Background Image causing memory warning and crash during UITesting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have a simple UITest which taps an item on the tool bar 100 times, running the test with no background image consistently passes, however when I add a background image I receive memory warnings followed by the test failing. I've tried numerous solutions for displaying the image, most all of them cause the same result, memory warnings followed by a crash. I have an image set consisting of three png images sized at 3X: 2304 X 3072, 2X: 1536 X 2048, and 1X: 768 X 1024, as per apple docs. How can I add a background image so that it wont cause memory issues.

UITesting Code:

```
func testJustNumberOfRolls() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    for _ in 1...100 {
        app.toolbars.buttons["Tip2"].tap()
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let image = UIImage(named: "feltSized") {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
        }
    }
}
```

Test Logs:

```
11:10:49.317 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual 

testJustNumberOfRolls] started activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x1314a5ab0> 2015-12-11 17:10:49 +0000: Wait for app to idle
11:10:49.528 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] Waiting for app quiescence...
11:10:49.529 XCTRunner[6768:2874357] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 1 -> 0
11:10:49.529 XCTRunner[6768:2874357] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 1 -> 0
11:10:49.530 XCTRunner[6768:2874357] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 1 -> 0
11:10:49.531 XCTRunner[6768:2874357] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 1 -> 0
11:10:49.535 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got AX notification 4002
11:10:49.536 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got animations reply.
11:10:49.536 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Animations are not active.
11:10:49.537 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got AX notification 4002
11:10:49.537 XCTRunner[6768:2874322] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 0 -> 1
11:10:49.538 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got event loop idle reply.
11:10:49.539 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Event loop is idle.
11:10:49.538 XCTRunner[6768:2874322] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 0 -> 1
11:10:49.540 XCTRunner[6768:2874322] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 0 -> 1
11:10:49.541 XCTRunner[6768:2874322] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 0 -> 1
11:10:49.542 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] App has quiesced.
11:10:49.542 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] finished activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x1314a5ab0> 2015-12-11 17:10:49 +0000: Wait for app to idle (0.225394s)
11:10:49.550 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] finished activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x1314a2970> 2015-12-11 17:10:49 +0000: Find the "Tip2" Button (0.298589s)
11:10:49.553 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] started activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x1314abf80> 2015-12-11 17:10:49 +0000: Synthesize event
11:10:49.966 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got AX notification 4002
11:10:49.967 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got event completion.
11:10:49.969 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] finished activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x1314abf80> 2015-12-11 17:10:49 +0000: Synthesize event (0.416638s)
11:10:49.973 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got AX notification 4002
11:10:49.988 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] started activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x1315415e0> 2015-12-11 17:10:49 +0000: Wait for app to idle
11:10:50.197 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] Waiting for app quiescence...
11:10:50.198 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 1 -> 0
11:10:50.198 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 1 -> 0
11:10:50.199 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 1 -> 0
11:10:50.200 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 1 -> 0
11:10:50.204 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] Got AX notification 4002
11:10:50.204 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] Got event loop idle reply.
11:10:50.205 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] Event loop is idle.
11:10:50.205 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 0 -> 1
11:10:50.206 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 0 -> 1
11:10:50.437 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] Got AX notification 4002
11:10:50.438 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] Got animations reply.
11:10:50.442 XCTRunner[6768:2874358] Animations are not active.
11:10:50.443 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 0 -> 1
11:10:50.444 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 0 -> 1
11:10:50.446 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] App has quiesced.
11:10:50.447 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] finished activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x1315415e0> 2015-12-11 17:10:49 +0000: Wait for app to idle (0.459272s)
11:10:50.460 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] finished activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x13149e5f0> 2015-12-11 17:10:49 +0000: Tap "Tip2" Button (1.4335s)
11:10:50.464 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] started activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x1314af0f0> 2015-12-11 17:10:50 +0000: Tap "Tip2" Button
11:10:50.466 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] started activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x131544810> 2015-12-11 17:10:50 +0000: Wait for app to idle
11:10:50.669 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] Waiting for app quiescence...
11:10:50.669 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 1 -> 0
11:10:50.670 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 1 -> 0
11:10:50.670 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 1 -> 0
11:10:50.671 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 1 -> 0
11:10:50.676 XCTRunner[6768:2874356] Got AX notification 4002
11:10:50.676 XCTRunner[6768:2874356] Got animations reply.
11:10:50.677 XCTRunner[6768:2874356] Animations are not active.
11:10:50.677 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 0 -> 1
11:10:50.677 XCTRunner[6768:2874567] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 0 -> 1
11:10:50.679 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got AX notification 4002
11:10:50.679 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Got event loop idle reply.
11:10:50.680 XCTRunner[6768:2874320] Event loop is idle.
11:10:50.680 XCTRunner[6768:2874357] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> hasReceivedAnimationsHaveFinished 0 -> 1
11:10:50.681 XCTRunner[6768:2874357] <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x12fe466a0 mikepland.crapsBuzzInSwift (6775)> event loop is idle 0 -> 1
11:10:50.682 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] App has quiesced.
11:10:50.682 XCTRunner[6768:2874277] -[TestingUIActual testJustNumberOfRolls] finished activity <XCActivityRecord: 0x131544810> 2015-12-11 17:10:50 +0000: Wait for app to idle (0.216641s)
11:10:50.718 Xcode[1265:207640] Test operation failure: Lost connection to test manager service.
11:10:50.719 Xcode[1265:207640] _finishWithError:Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=4 "Lost connection to test manager service." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Lost connection to test manager service.} didCancel: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I tried not displaying ANY images, this seems to be better. Error shows up at 'lost connection to test manager services'.

At this point I have refactored my app to avoid long animations to avoid needing a timeout on my tests, then recoded app to hide ALL images and background colors. Even then the error still shows up, although tests are able to run for longer.

I was able to replicate on a brand new app with just a background pattern and a button, even that was causing the error if running tests for more than a few minutes, and thats a BRAND NEW APP. So idk what else to do, hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Comment: If your answer doesn't work, you should delete it or at least unaccept it, and update your question with the necessary information. Thanks!